# How to display specific file extention in C

Tags: c

How can I display files with extension ".txt" only in C using execl or execve?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

 ( execl("/bin/ls","*.txt",NULL); 

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why using only execl or execve?

Comment: Well, you could `execl("/bin/sh", "-c", "/bin/ls *.txt", NULL)` but I suspect that you want to do something else, since the `exec*()` family of functions will effectively terminate your program.  (They *replace* your program with the program you specify.)

Comment: @cdhowie no nothing else the program should be terminated but it does not work with me !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for [`glob(3)`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?glob+3):

```
#include <glob.h>

extern char **environ;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    glob_t g={0};

    g.gl_offs = 1; /* reserve slot for "/bin/ls" */
    glob("*.txt",GLOB_DOOFFS,0,&g);
    g.gl_pathv[0] = "/bin/ls";
    execve(*g.gl_pathv,g.gl_pathv,environ);

}
```